# Know the exactly date of N years ago

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have this request about python dates ...
I would to know the exactly date of N_YEARS ago.
So, I tried this simple code:

```
years_count = N_YEARS * 365
today = datetime.datetime.today()
birthday_date = today + datetime.timedelta(days=-years_count)
```

But this is not correct.
Example:

```
Today: 28/05/2015 (DD/MM/YYYY)
N_YEARS: 18
Result: 1997-06-01 (YYYY/MM/DD) **17 Years, 11 Months e 27 Days**
```

`timedelta` function is correct by is not correct to calculate the count of days in this way: `N_YEARS * 365`
How can I solve it?

Comment: `N_YEARS * 365` is indeed not correct. Ever heard of leap years?

Comment: A year is not an exact unit. Some years have 365 days, others have 366.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by exactly N years. I'd say just substract N years from your date. 1000 years does *not* equal 365000 days! More like 365260, but it's a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace):

```
today = today.replace(year = today.year - N_YEARS)
```

EDIT: Note if `today` is Feb 29 and the resulting year is not a leap year, it will throw an error:

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 29)
>>> a.replace(year=a.year - 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Comment: Is your response compatible with leap years? Is correct to replace the years with today.year - N_YEARS? For example ... if my birthday is 28/02/1970 ?

Comment: I tried to use yrs_ago_date = datetime.datetime.today() - relativedelta(years=N_YEARS)  The date is calculated correctly... What do you think about this?